# how to return different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have in my Java code these arrays:

```
private String[] arrayT1V1;
private String[] arrayT1V2;
private String[] arrayT1V3;
private String[] arrayT2V1;
private String[] arrayT2V2;
private String[] arrayT2V3;
```

Is there a way to change the String[] I'm addressing programatically? I tried something like the code bellow, which I know it's wrong! I can't have two different objects with the same name. I posted it just to better explain what I want.

```
private String[] createStringArrays(int type, int value, int size) {
        for (int i = 1; i == type; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j == value; j++) {
                String arrayName = "arrayT" + type + "V" + value;
                String[] arrayName = new String[size];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe use a Map to store your Arrays, and get them with their name, like:

```
Map<String, String[]> mapArrays = new HashMap<String, String[]>();


String arrayName = "arrayT" + type + "V" + value;
mapArrays.put(arrayName, new String[size]);
```

To get them you'd use a

```
String[] someArray = mapArrays.get(arrayName);
```

Comment: Interesting! I'll try this! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use an [array of arrays](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-12/01-qa-array.html?page=1), so that you can use `arrayTV[2][3]` instead of `arrayT2V3`.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
private String[][] arrayTV;
```